# How to step up my site like this?

Tags: c#

I have made a sample page, which has a logo page. It asks the user to state its department according to which the page will show the department logo.

I want to separate the website access by copying the webpage on different computers and hosting such that each computer represent a department (the webpage shows the text "welcome to department" which I have edited by department name for each department computer).

When user says:

- www.select_your_department.com computer1 is used as IIS server
- user says my department is alpha
- computer1 one does response.redirect to showmydepartment.aspx which has a page saying "welcome to alpha" (that is this page is coming from the cpu dedicated for department alpha)

But how to achieve this in practical?

Even if I copy the page on all the departments computer and edit it department name, the page still has the same name "showmydepartment". How to ask browser to fetch the page from particular hosting server?

I think it involves something like department.showmydepartment and some domain names.

Comment: You must clarify your question and problem. Because this is very difficult to read/understand.

Comment: its difficult for me too :-) i will

Comment: This is too broad, unclear, maybe also opinion-based. I've removed a 404 explanatory image as well, so this is impossible to answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly this sounds like a really bad idea. A better solution would be to developer the application based on a single computer and implement clustering if the load is too great for a single machine.

The posters idea of spreading the website across several machines has little chance of handling load situations and will be a development and maintenance nightmare.

Comment: ok but if i want to know how its done? do you have any guides

Comment: Ok, but the way you describe what you want to do suggests that you want different on different machines. Generally speaking you don't want to do this unless you have a really massive system. In which case you would have a really big dev team too. You only need to uses clusters when the load you are expecting will exceed the capacity of a single machine. IN that case the cluster software will handle distributing the application and user sessions across the nodes in the cluster. I'd suggest http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html as a good start.